# Help post permalink

Tags: posts

How can I change the `-` to a `+` in the URLs, automatically?

```
http://website.com/post-name/
http://website.com/post+name/
```

Comment: Do you want to do it manually or automatically when the post is created?

Comment: yes automatically

Comment: What is your permalink structure (update your question please)?

Comment: have you tried custom structure in Permalink settings?

Answer (score 0):

The `post slug` is generated in the `wp_insert_post` (…/wp-includes/post.php) function. The function calls another function to sanitize the your `post title`. You can use the filter `sanitize_title` (…/wp-includes/formatting.php) to replace `-` by `+`. This will change the behavior in more situations then just the title of a post. So you should check if it is a post title that is sanitized.